# Scala: parsing an API parameter

Tags: scala

My API currently take an optional parameter named gamedate. It is passed in as a string at which time I later parse it to a Date object using some utility code. The code looks like this:

```
 val gdate:Option[String] = params.get("gamedate")
 val res = gdate match {
   case Some(s) => {
     val date:Option[DateTime] = gdate map { MyDateTime.parseDate _ }
     val dateOrDefault:DateTime = date.getOrElse((new DateTime).withTime(0, 0, 0, 0))
     NBAScoreboard.findByDate(dateOrDefault)
   }  
   case None => NBAScoreboard.getToday
 }
```

This works just fine. Now what I'm trying to solve is I'm allowing multiple gamedates get passed in via a comma delimited list. Originally you can pass a parameter like this:

`gamedate=20131211`

now I want to allow that OR:

`gamedate=20131211,20131212`

That requires modifying the code above to try to split the comma delimited string and parse each value into a Date and change the interface to findByDate to accept a Seq[DateTime] vs just DateTime. I tried running something like this, but apparently it's not the way to go about it:

```
val res = gdates match {
      case Some(s) => {
        val dates:Option[Seq[DateTime]] = gdates map { _.split(",").distinct.map(MyDateTime.parseDate _ )}
        val datesOrDefault:Seq[DateTime] = dates map { _.getOrElse((new DateTime).withTime(0, 0, 0, 0))}
        NBAScoreboard.findByDates(datesOrDefault)
      }  
      case None => NBAScoreboard.getToday 
    }
```

What's the best way to convert my first set of code to handle this use case? I'm probably fairly close in the second code example I provided, but I'm just not hitting it right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mixed up the containers. The `map` you call on `dates` unpackes the `Option` so the `getOrElse` is applied to a list.

```scala
val res = gdates match {
  case Some(s) => 
    val dates = gdates.map(_.split(",").distinct.map(MyDateTime.parseDate _ ))
    val datesOrDefault = dates.getOrElse(Array((new DateTime).withTime(0, 0, 0, 0)))
    NBAScoreboard.findByDates(datesOrDefault)

  case _ => 
    NBAScoreboard.getToday 
}
```

This should work.

Comment: Seems your code still breaks on getOrElse() however. `value getOrElse is not a member of Array[org.joda.time.DateTime]`